# numpy assign values from another array using indices

Tags: python, numpy

I have this `points` ndarray.

```
In [141]: points
Out[141]:
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7]])
```

And I have this classifier that I classified the points into two classes

```
In [142]: i5
Out[142]: array([0, 0, 1, 1])
```

Note, the length of points and i5 are same.

I know that the two classes have these values.

```
In [143]: c
Out[143]:
array([[2, 3],
       [4, 5]])
```

I want to assign the points to the values that I have classified. The final result that i expect is

```
In [141]: points
Out[141]:
array([[2, 3],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [4, 5]])
```

How can I mutate/change `points` based on `c` indexed on `i5`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `i5` as an index array on `c` and assign the indexed view on `c` to `points`

```
import numpy as np

c = np.array([[2, 3],
              [4, 5]])

i5 = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1])

points = c[i5]

# [[2 3]
#  [2 3]
#  [4 5]
#  [4 5]]
```

Note: Based on how you've described the problem, the initial value of `points` doesn't appear to matter. Is that an appropriate conclusion to derive?

Comment: only after I wrote this question, I realized that after calculating the classification values i5 (using values in points), they are not used. So, you described is a correct solution for me.